# Is it a good practice to provide check the instance type in the base class

Tags: java, c++

I have four classes. A,B,D are derived classes, and C is the base class. If the given instance is A or D, return true; Otherwise, return false. Below is my codes:

```
 //A.java
 public class A extends C{
 }

 //B.java 
 public class B extends C {
 }

 //D.java
 public class D extends C {
 }

 //C.java
 public class C {
     public boolean isSupported(C object){
         boolean result= false;

         // Object type check
         if(object instanceof A || object instanceof D){ // A, D
            result=true;
          }
          else {  // B, C
            result=false;
          }
       return result;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        C tmp = new A();
        System.out.println(tmp.isSupported());
     }
 }
```

So is it a good practice to check the instance/object type in isSupported() of the base class C? (For C++, if four classes are defined in the different files, if I do so, I have to include the header files defining the Class A and D in the file providing the implementation of Class C, which is a little bit strange).

I know I can provide a override function in each of derived class. But is it kind of duplicate codes especially if I have a lot of derived classes.

Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: This reeks of poor design. B shouldn't be a base class of C if it isn't "supported".

Answer (score 4):

You should override `isSupported` in the subclasses so that `A` and `D` override it to return `true` and `C` defines the default behavior (returning `false`) and `B` inherits that default behavior from `C` without overriding.

```
public class C {
    public boolean isSupported() {
        return false;
    }
}

public class A extends C {
    @Override
    public boolean isSupported() {
        return true;
    }
}

public class B extends C {
    // inherits isSupported from C
}

public class D extends C {
    @Override
    public boolean isSupported() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is more or less how the JDK handles this with the Collection classes. E.g., `AbstractCollection`, implements the `clear` method by throwing an `UnsupportedOperationException`. Derived classes for which the method is supported override with the desired functionality, others where it's not supported take the default behavior (throwing the exception) from the base class.

Comment: But if I have a lot of derived classes, does it mean I need to define a override function in each of these?

Comment: Personally, I always felt that offering a method via your interface but then throw an UnsupportedOperationException to be horribly smelly.

Comment: @longli No, you only  override `isSupported` in the subclasses that should return true.

Answer (score 2):

A base class should never need to know anything about classes extending it. Otherwise you would need to modify the base class when extending it. I would consider that very bad style (in other word, it "smells" - no, that's not an insult - see "[code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)").

Why do you need to do that?